# How to implement an array-like indexer ([ ]) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to implement a collection in Javascript - is there anyway to implement an array-like indexer for elements in my collection?

So far, I have the following code:

```
var Collection = function() {

    var collection = [];

    var addAccessor = function(api, name) {
      if (toString.call(collection[name]) == '[object Function]') {
        api[name] = (function(){
          return function () {
            return collection[name](arguments);
          };
        }());
      }
      else {
        Object.defineProperty(api, name, {
          get: function() { return collection.length; },
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: true
        });
      }
    };

    var publicApi = {};

    var methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype);
    for(var i = 0, len = methods.length; i < len; ++i) {
      var method = methods[i];
      addAccessor(publicApi, method);
    }

    return publicApi;
  };
};
```

All of the `Array.prototype` methods and properties work as expected.

```
var c = Collection();
c.push(4);
console.log(c.length);  // 1
```

But the one thing I can't figure out is how to get the following to work:

```
console.log(c[0]);     // should print 4, currently undefined
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You can't. Any specific reason you're not just using an `Array`?

Comment: I think something is missing in your code. `collection` is never populated, so no Array prototypes are copied. Can you post a working fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "extend" Array, the classic way would be something like:

```
function Collection(){};
Collection.prototype = new Array();
Collection.constructor = Collection;
```

Now add your own methods:

```
Collection.prototype.color = function() {
    this.push('color');
};
```

And use it with `new`:

```
var myArray = new Collection();
myArray.push(1);
myArray.color();
```

If you want to add a new `push` method that access Array push, try:

```
Collection.prototype.push = function() {
    console.log('pushed!');
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
};
```

Comment: This is where I started, but then I needed to raise events on some Array methods.  How would I override `Collection.prototype.push` in this case so that I can execute my own code while still pushing the element onto the array?

Comment: `Array.prototype.push.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));` results in a stack overflow.

Comment: Missed the change to the prototype declaration and that was what I missed when I first tried to implement it this way which sent me on my wild goose chase... This works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `Collection.prototype = Array.prototype` instead of `... = new Array()`? That should also include any future additions to the Array prototype itself.

Comment: I found the difference: My suggestion connects both prototypes and altering Collection.prototype also affects the base Array.prototype. Using a new Array() avoids that and should be preferred. Future additions to Array.prototype (in this case) are available in new Collection instances anyway.

Answer (score 0):

using classes:

```js
class Collection extends Array {
  color() {
    this.push('color')
  }
}
```